# New site theme about to launch

Tags: discussion

As has been announced before all sites on the Stackexchange Network will get a new site theme.

For launch schedule and discussions refer to:

[Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes)

Beta sites like us will get this stock theme:

[image]
[image]